# Why is the indent of my headings changing on odd pages

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, styles, text-formatting

I have a document in MS Word. On even pages, my H1 and H2 headings look like this:
[image: H1 and H2 inline]

But on odd pages they look like this:

[image: H2 moves to the left]

How is the indent on the H2 heading being modified on the odd pages? This is driving my OCD crazy.

If text flow pushes the headings to a new page you see this happen, or if you insert a page break.

Looking at the paragraph settings, and looking at the ruler, nothing seems to change at all.

Comment: Go to the list of paragraph *styles*, select the Heading 2 style, Modify it, then click the Format... button and select Paragraph... In there, is "Mirror indents" checked, and if so, are there different values in the Inside and Outside boxes? (This seems like the obvious place to start but I suspect it is not the only possibility).

Answer (score 2):

This is driving me crazy too. I unchecked "mirror indents" under paragraph, and it solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
Page setup > Layout

Uncheck "Different odd and even".

Comment: Are you referring the the "Different odd and even" checkbox in the header and footer section of Layout? It is already unchecked. 
I would be disappointed if a header and footer option affected the body of the document though.

Comment: Can you attach shot for ruler or upload sample doc file to check with you?